# Install Java 12 in Ubuntu 14

Tags: java, ubuntu-14.04

I want to Install Java 11 or 12 on my Ubuntu 14 machine. As of now, I'm isntalling 12.

To Install, I've downloaded Java at below location and extracted too at same location.

```
/usr/lib/jvm
/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-12.0.1
```

After that, I've added JAVA_HOME path in environment file

```
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games"
JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-12.0.1/"
export JAVA_HOME
```

But when I check `java -version`, It shows me below error

```
The program 'java' can be found in the following packages:
 * default-jre
 * gcj-4.8-jre-headless
 * openjdk-7-jre-headless
 * gcj-4.6-jre-headless
 * openjdk-6-jre-headless
Try: sudo apt-get install <selected package
```

May I know please, What am doing wrong....?

Thanks

Comment: JAVA_HOME is only checked by certain applications. To be able to run an executable - whether java or not - you need to add the directory that program is in to the **`PATH`** environment variable. Look for directories named `bin`.

Comment: Beyond that: consider upgrading your Ubuntu. Doesn't it have end of life already?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As correctly pointed out in the comments by [RealSkeptic](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4125191/realskeptic), the `JAVA_HOME` environment variable is not utilized by your shell to detect where the java runtime is located.

Try adding the following to the line to your environment file after `export JAVA_HOME`

```
export PATH=${JAVA_HOME}/bin:${PATH}
```

If your `JAVA_HOME` is set correctly it should be added correctly to your `PATH`